# Why does 1+1=0 (buttons and functions)

Tags: function, button, addition

I've been trying to make my own scuffed calculator by running an html file into google chrome and plugging js and css into it (Note I'm relatively new to coding). For the calculator, I use a series of buttons and when one is pressed, it calls a function relating to the button. Example,
`<button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="one()">1</button>`.

That button increase both x and y by 1.

```
function one() {
    x = x+1
    y = y+1
    console.log(x,y)
}
```

In the console it says x and y are equal to 1.
`var answer = x + y`
is the other variable I have but when I log it, I get 0. Any tips?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code, read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it's right!, x and y are equal to 1 because you didn't define initial values to x and y. First you should define initial values to x and y.
like `x = 0; y = 0;`